# Increment upload size Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to increment the file size of Wordpress.

I've tried to change the php.ini file in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini :

```
upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 10M
```

I've tried adding to my theme's functions:

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

I've tried adding to the .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

Also I've tried to install a plugin called "Increase Upload Max Filesize" and the plugin is telling me:

```
Your upload_max_filesize was already 128M.
Your post_max_size was 16M.
```

After trying each of these 4 methods I've restarted apache service, but none of these is working, when I go to "Add media" Wordpress shows me that the maximum filesize is 1MB.

What's wrong?

Comment: Make sure php.ini does not contain errors and php pulls settings from the expected php.ini file.

Comment: On windows  or linux server?

Comment: @NextDeveloper There's no errors on php.ini, also the Wordpress plugin is showing me the correct php.ini values: Your upload_max_filesize was already 128M. Your post_max_size was 16M. But then when I go to media uploader Wordpress shows me maximum 1 MB permitted.

Comment: @batz I'm using linux server

Comment: have you tried uploading file more than 1MB?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In the end turned out there were 2 php.ini files. 1 in "php" files, and one in "phpmyadmin" files. When i changed both problem solved but not sure this what you are facing. Something similar is mentioned [here](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/php.ini).

Comment: I just checked which php.ini is apache loading (phpinfo()) and upload_max_filesize = 128M, post_max_size = 16M

Comment: Could be your on shared hosting that somehow overrides your php settings ?

Comment: Maybe try a lower number from 128M , like 30 50 70

Comment: Still the same issue \o/